# Using IMPORTHTML, how would I take the table for the 2 or 3 tabs within investing.com's Real Time Commodity Futures Prices

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula

Trying to acquire the "Performance" table in Google Sheets using this link: https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures

**I have tried:**
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures","table",1)

But it only comes back with the first tab "Price" table. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible. "Performance" table is controlled by JavaScript and google sheets IMPORT functions are not able to work with / scrape JS content

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!